# adobe flex air call jar

Tags: apache-flex, air, jar, adobe, call

We have an executable jar file that can be run from the command line and it runs continuously to perform some file related tasks.

```
java -jar 'fileTester.jar' 'params'
```

Also we have an Adobe AIR client which needs to kick start this jar command. How can we invoke the jar file command from Flex? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the feature you need is called NativeProcess.  Here are some docs on it:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html

http://www.seriousmagic.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/air_screenrecording.html